# Slack bot permission to post on any channel by any user

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slash, slack-commands

I have created a slash command on `Slack` and it works fine if I execute it on any channel. I can't figure out if there is a permission through which `any user` can post on `any channel` using the slash command.

Is there a way where any user can post anywhere in the channel ?

[image]

Basically I want to pass `*` to `Post to` option so that they are not restricted to a private slackbot group only.

EDITED:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app does not need any additional permissions for replying to the slash command of a user in any channel.

There are two ways on how to post into a channel as response to a slash command executed by a user:

- Directly respond to the slash request within 3 seconds. e.g. if you are using Flask you are responding to a request by calling return in your @route function
- Send a request to the `request_url` which you find the slash command request within 30 seconds

The "Post To" property you are showing has nothing to do with slash commands. It's for incoming-webhooks, which is used by non Slack apps to send message to Slack.

## Code

Here is an example for both types of response using Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, json, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__) #create the Flask app

@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def slash_response_direct():                
    """Direct response"""
    message = {        
        "text": "Hi there"
    }
    return json.jsonify(message)


#@app.route('/slash', methods=['POST'])
def slash_response_indirect():
    """responding to slash command via response URL"""

    response_url = request.form["response_url"]    
    message = {        
        "text": "Hi"
    }
    res = requests.post(response_url, json=message)

    return ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000) #run app in debug mode on port 8000
```

Comment: For `Slash` command if you have to select a channel and you define in `Post to` field. I think for posting to all the channels by any user you need enterprise level subscription.

Comment: No. There is no permission in Slack that allows you to post to every channel Not even the Slack owner can do that.

Comment: Why can't the slash command be used in direct messages by other users? I can use it anywhere since I created it.

Comment: That is not accurate. In general a slash command can be used by any user in any channel. Including direct message channels. What issue are you having?

Comment: I have updated the question with one more screenshot. Why do I need to select a particular channel to post it for a `slash` command ? also check the permissions

Comment: There is something different about posting to `IM Private Conversation`. If I am not the part of the group then it's considered a private conversation. Maybe I am missing a permission I am not aware of.

Comment: yes. if you are not a member of a private channel, you can not post to it. As I said that is how Slack's security works and there is no permission to fix that. But if a user in a private channel runs your slash command. Your app can still respond to that user in that private channel. As I explained above. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Yes I will use response_url instead of channel_id. That might work.